# add Round Button on ScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I want to make a **button** that is not scrolled when i scroll the scrollView like in this **Big Basket app ScreenShot** **right bottom corner** `roundButtonWithImageOFBasket`

[image]

I tried it. My code is here

```
     @interface homeViewController ()<UIScrollViewDelegate>
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *addButton;
@end

@implementation homeViewController
@synthesize addButton;   
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

Image *btnImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cross"];
    [addButton setBackgroundImage:btnImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    CGRect floatFrame = CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 44 - 20, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - 44 - 20, 44, 44);
    addButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:floatFrame];
     [self.view.window  addSubview:addButton];
}
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    CGRect floatFrame = self.addButton.frame;
    floatFrame.origin.y = 0 + scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    self.addButton.frame = floatFrame;
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:self.addButton];
}
```

**It's do nothing, I don't know, where I did mistakes or what I forgot to do implement.**
Any suggestion any advice or any demo.

Comment: @iphonic , i want a button that not scrolled when i scroll the scrollView  like in this image , i have image that is already round.

Comment: Add your UIButton to your UIView: `[self.view addSubview:addButton];` then bring it to the front after you setup your UI, no need to do it in `scrollViewDidScroll` the whole time.

Comment: change this line  [self.view.window  addSubview:addButton] to      [self.view  addSubview:addButton]; as @Jasper said..

Comment: how to bring button to the front @Jasper

Comment: its also do nothing @leena

Comment: You already wrote the line of code to do that in your scrollViewDidScroll method Sharma.. Just put it after you setup your UI, the last line of viewDidLoad f.e.

Comment: the only issue i can see is that may be you are not setting frame properly or you are not adding button properly.

Comment: Are you using AutoLayout ? In that case simply set a constraint between the button and the controller's view

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to set the image after `alloc`. And add button to the view(Not the `UIScrollView` or `UIWindow`). And remove the code inside `scrollviewDidScroll`

```
CGRect floatFrame = CGRectMake([UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width - 44 - 20, [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height - 44 - 20, 44, 44);
addButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:floatFrame];
Image *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"cross"];
[addButton setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[self.view addSubview:addButton];
```